# What kind of FPGA board for sha-256 algo

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I am newbie in VHDL and FPGA, i was searching for an answer to my question but didn't find any good answer.
In my projet i have a `.txt` file containing a `hexadecimal` data, i want to send this data to an FPGA, `256-hash` it, and then send the hashed data back to my laptop in another `.txt` file.

To do this task what kind of FPGA do i need to buy?

PS: I want a speed and not expensive one, if it's possible

Help is appreciated

Comment: Questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic on EE.SE

Comment: How are you sending it from the laptop and back? Ethernet, USB, Serial?

Comment: @colin No matter how to send it,  i need the easiest and the faster way, thank you

Comment: @Hamita "easiest" and "fastest" are opposites, unfortunately. How many gigabytes is the text file?

Comment: @pjc50 The size is 155 bytes, the text file contains one line of hex data, and it's generated by another application (writen with VB.net) every 2 seconds the hex data change, so doing the hash with my CPU will slow my laptop

Comment: @Hamita even fairly basic PCs can manage a million SHA-256 per second. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Non-specialized_hardware_comparison#CPUs.2FAPUs The time for such a small file is going to be dominated by opening and reading it.

Comment: The FPGA itself can easily be faster than the CPU ... but getting data into and out of it is not. So if speed is your concern for such trivial processing, use the host CPU.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, and if the speed isn't the concern, what kind of FGPA can i use? An Altera Cyclone IV can do that easly?

Comment: First you have to find out how many gates the algorithm will take, then estimate if it will fit in an FPGA. Many FPGA softwares come in an eval version, you could synthesize the code and then select which FPGA you would need. Digital logic an coding is very difficult if nothing has been done in that arena before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect this to be possible with the "icestick" FPGA cards. However, SHA-256 is likely to be memory-bandwidth limited on most PCs, so in almost all cases it would be faster to do it on the CPU than transmit it anywhere and back again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so you think the CPU is faster than the Icestick FPGA?

Comment: The performance of the fpga solution is dependant on the implementation of the sha algorithm. Your average PC cpu is pretty fast, so you're going to have to think carefully with your implementation to beat it. Then you have the issue of getting the data in, do sha then output it. The i/o is usually the bottleneck. By 'hexadecimal' I'm assuming you mean binary data - unless it is an Intel Hex file, it is unlikely you'd store the data in hexadecimal.

Comment: @kartman In my ```.txt``` file i have data like this ```e17ab68ccd0f37decb6```

Comment: @Hamita CPU is going to be faster than "transmit to FPGA, do work, transmit back again", unless you go for a very expensive solution